# Get results from multiple tables based on relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I have dbo.Users tables

```
Id, Name
1, John
2, Mary
3, Michael
```

Then I have dbo.Phones table

```
Id, Phonenumber
10, 1234
11, 5555
```

Then I have dbo.Relationship table

```
Id, ChildId
1, 10
2, 11
```

How could I make a query that returns

```
Id, Name, Phonenumber
1, John, 1234
2, Mary, 5555
3, Michael, NULL
```

This is what I got so far.

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Name, p.Phonenumber
FROM dbo.Users as u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phones as p
-- Something
```

[<kbd>SQL Fiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8fe7/3)

Comment: Are there PK/FK relationships setup?  Not that it matters, but there should be.

Comment: Yes, PK/FK are setup. FK's in relationship table and PK on users and phones tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the Relationship table as the middle-man between your Users and Phones tables here. It is a [many-to-many relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_xtox/%20%22many-to-many%20relationship) with a mapping table.  Join your Users to the Relationship and then the Relationship to your Phones.

```
SELECT u.Id
    ,u.Name
    ,p.PhoneNumber
FROM dbo.Users u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Relationship r ON r.Id = u.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phones p ON p.Id = r.ChildId
```

Think of it like:

**Users:** Hello Relationship, I have UserId = 1, what PhoneIds do I have for that UserId?

**Relationship:** Hi Users. I have PhoneId = 10 for you. I'll go talk to Phones to see what the number is.

**Phones:** Hi Relationships! I have PhoneNumber 1234 for you. It matches the PhoneId you gave me.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation justiceorjustus and thanks for the extra reading AddcitedToLearn!

Comment: @Pegaz Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score -1):

Join them on id field.I would use inner join depending on the requirement

```
SELECT distinct u.Id, u.Name, p.Phonenumber
FROM dbo.Users as u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Phones as p on u.id = p.id
```

or---

```
 SELECT distinct u.Id, u.Name, p.Phonenumber
    FROM dbo.Users as u
    inner join T JOIN dbo.Phones as p on u.id = p.id
    inner join dbo.relationship r on r.id = u.id
where----
```

Comment: Probably needs a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in case the record doesn't exist (showing Users w/o Phone Numbers)

Comment: @sqlmason hasnt mentioned in the actual question to eliminate users without phone numbers, i assume giving diversity of joins will help understand novice for better understanding. Thanks anyway

Comment: `3, Michael, NULL`  Your query would not show this expected record.

Comment: @BHouse Users does not contain the PhoneId.  The Relationship table is a many-to-many between Users and Phones.

Comment: @BHouse Just so you can see what we're talking about.  Check out this SQLFiddle I made for you: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8fe7/3)

Comment: @SQLMason Thats nice one, Appreciate it. I have assumed from the info given above id in first table is not an auto increment id column, it doesnt clearly say, id's in every table are different. A simple assumptions id's are referring to same with primary-foreign relationship, instead of joinign on childid. Thanks anyway

Comment: The relationship table really should have the columns "UserID" and "PhoneID" instead of "ID" and "ChildID" to be more clear of the intent.  Maybe the OP thinks that this relationship table will be used for other tables, but then he'll need to add a table id and things get harry.  Thanks for your attempt and glad I was able to help clear it up a bit.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
Select u.Id, u.Name, p.Phonenumber
From
Users u 
Left join Relationship r on r.Id = u.Id
Left join Phones p on r.ChildId = p.Phonenumber
```